# Show all points in a plot with Pyplot on Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

So I'm new to Pyplot and I was able to show a standard x,y plot.

Now my issue is that I have a series of point in the form of (time,percentage) but I have multiple percentage with the same time. For istance:

```
x(time) y(percentage)
0:0:1   3
0:0:1   4
0:0:1   2
0:0:1   1
0:0:2   1
0:0:2   3
0:0:2   2
```

For some reason `plt.plot` plot only one value for `0:0:1` and `0:0:2` but I would like to plot every value on the x axis, even if they have the same value.

I'm using `plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()` for the x axis

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: No, `plt.plot` plots everything, try `plt.plot(x, y, "-*")` …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this helps as I'm not sure if your dataset is fixed, but you could display it thru `plt.xticks` though you might need to change or modify your initial dataset.

Assuming below is your code:

```
data = {
    'x(time)':['0:0:1a','0:0:1b','0:0:1c','0:0:1d','0:0:2e','0:0:2f','0:0:2g'],
    'y(percentage)': [3,4,2,1,1,3,2]
}
print(data)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
print(df)
your_label = ['0:0:1','0:0:1','0:0:c','0:0:1','0:0:2','0:0:2','0:0:2']
```

Then you would plot it using the code:

```
plt.scatter(x='x(time)', y='y(percentage)', data=df)
plt.xticks(ticks=df['x(time)'], labels=your_label)
plt.show()
```

`plt.xticks` will generate new labels for your plot. Of course, you could use a generator like `np.arange` to generate the labels for you, but that would be dependent on whether your initial dataset can be modified in the first place.

I look forward to other people's reply too.

Comment: I used a similar solution; instead of adding letters I've added a new number at the end in the form of 0.0:1.0 0:0:1.1 etc